# Mule 3.9.0 - Mule Throw Exception without executing exception flow (exception strategy)

Tags: mule, mule-esb

How to Handle this exception? 
Mule throw exception without executing exception flow in case I sent wrong encoding value (UTF-88) in Content-Type.

WARN  2017-12-22 10:19:55,733 [[2017-mule_api_registry-uni_auth_app].HttpConnectoConfig.worker.02] org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener: Exception occurred parsing request:
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: UTF-88
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:531) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at org.mule.transformer.types.SimpleDataType.setEncoding(SimpleDataType.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.updateDataTypeWithProperty(DefaultMuleMessage.java:551) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.setProperty(DefaultMuleMessage.java:502) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.setProperty(DefaultMuleMessage.java:494) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.addProperties(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1398) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.(DefaultMuleMessage.java:198) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.(DefaultMuleMessage.java:175) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpRequestToMuleEvent.transform(HttpRequestToMuleEvent.java:128) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener.createEvent(DefaultHttpListener.java:187) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener.access$000(DefaultHttpListener.java:48) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:133) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:100) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:119) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:31) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:142) ~[mule-module-http-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]

Answer (score 0):

1.Use a MEL expression in each  element to test the Content-Type header:

> #[message.inboundProperties['Content-Type'].contains('UTF-8')]

2.Use the  element to act as the default statement of a switch: throw your exception from there.

eg :

```
 <choice>
     <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['Content-Type'].contains('??????? your required content type ??????')]">
           <logger message="when number one invoked" level="WARN"/>
      </when>
      <otherwise>
           <logger message="otherwise invoked" level="WARN"/>
      </otherwise>
 </choice>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, Actually the request is not received in my flow at all,  this exception happen in "DefaultHttpListener" while parsing the request even when I set parseRequest=false  <http:listener config-ref="HttpConnectoConfig" path="*" doc:name="API" parseRequest="false">

Answer (score 0):

In mule core, there is a class **org.mule.transformer.types.SimpleDataType.java** which is responsible for this exception. The method **setEncoding** checks the validity of the charset and for invalid charset, **Charset.forname** method throws **UnsupportedCharsetException**. To avoid this you can modify the code block like this-

```
public void setEncoding(String encoding)
{
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(encoding))
    {
        try {
            // Checks that the encoding is valid and supported
            Charset.forName(encoding);
        }catch(UnsupportedCharsetException e) {
            encoding = "UTF-8";
        }
    }

    this.encoding = encoding;
}
```

You have to set a default charset, otherwise you can not get the payload from the MuleMessage instance like-

```
message.getPayloadAsString();
```

In my case, I set it 'UTF-8'. You can set it based on your need.